# Consulta sobre base de datos phpmyadmin y código php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Buenas tardes compañeros, acudo nuevamente a pedir su ayuda y encontrar el error que me esta generando el siguiente mensaje:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\url\validar.php on line 11
```

el código es el siguiente:

```
<?php
require 'includes/db.php';
session_start();

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$contraseña = $_POST['contraseña'];

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as contar FROM usuarios where usuario = '$usuario' and contraseña = '$contraseña'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$array = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

if($array['contar']>0){

    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    header("Location: home.php");
       
}
else{
    ?>
    <?php
    include('./index.php');
    ?>
    <h1 class="bad">Datos Incorrectos</h1>
    <?php
    
}
```

El código ya lo tenia trabajando hace aproximadamente hace 2 meses, pero ahora que retome el proyecto me arrogo el warning y no he podido encontrar la solución. espero me puedan auxiliar, agradezco su ayuda. Saludos compañeros.

Comment: Ese error significa que la base de datos está devolviendo `false`, o sea, hay algo mal en la consulta. Verifica si esos campos tienen el nombre correcto en la BD. Por otro lado, si, amamos el Español, pero evita en lo posible tildes o ñ en: Nombres de variables, BD, Campos, Tablas, etc. Verifica si el cotejamiento de la BD es el conveniente. Prueba usando back ticks en la parte `...and \`contraseña\` = '$contraseña'...`

Comment: Jejeje, buen punto olvide el tema de puede generar conflicto la ñ. Probaré y de ante mano agradezco tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

La advertencia:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
> bool given

Y similares, indican que el parámetro que pasas a la función es un boleano, no un recurso. Eso ocurre porque la consulta falló, o porque la conexión es nula, o simplemente porque no has configurado adecuadamente el juego de caracteres en tu entorno y el código se está rompiendo (esto último lo digo porque veo que declaras variables con `ñ`, deberías evitar `ñ` y acentos en nombres de variables, tablas, columnas, etc).

Aparte de lo dicho, cometes el error que yo llamo *programación optimista*. Consiste en escribir un programa pensando que todo ira bien siempre. Resulta que no todo va bien siempre y tu tarea como programador es prever lo que pueda salir mal (*programación pesimista*), para afrontarlo.

Tu código también es vulnerable a ataques de *inyección SQL*. En la respuesta implementaré consultas preparadas para neutralizar ese gravísimo riesgo ([revisa la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php) para entender lo que se ha hecho en esa parte).

Te propongo entonces lo siguiente:

```
<?php
require 'includes/db.php';
session_start();

$user = $_POST['usuario']    ?? null;
$pass = $_POST['contraseña'] ?? null;

if ($user && $pass) 
{
    if ($conn) 
    {
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS contar FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ? AND contraseña = ?";
        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)) 
        {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $user, $pass);  
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $contar);
            mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
            if($contar>0)
            {
                $_SESSION['usuario'] = $user;
                header("Location: home.php");
                exit();                
            }
            else{
                include('./index.php');
                echo '<h1 class="bad">Datos Incorrectos</h1>';                              
            }               
        }
        else{
            echo "Error preparando la consulta";
        }   
    } 
    else{
        echo "Error de conexión";
    }
} 
else{
    echo "No hay datos en el POST";
}
?>
```

Así debería funcionar y verás en pantalla lo que ocurre. Si no ves nada, entonces deberás verificar la codificación en tu entorno: HTML, PHP, Base de datos (conexión y datos).